# How to include 3rd party dependencies in Nx library

Tags: webpack, monorepo, nrwl-nx

New to Nx and not sure yet when it makes sense to extract code into libraries...
Is it possible/does it make sense to build an Nx library using a 3rd party dependency (let's say angular material) and then use this library in an app that doesn't use angular material itself? If so, do I need to use a buildable or publishable library for this?

Comment: Hey @Patric, 
Did you figure it out? I am also new to Nx and I also have a similar use case.

Comment: Hi @ApurvaOjas I did not.. So far I just avoided to do this. But would be nice to have some feedback from the nx devs, how can they be reached?!

Comment: shure you could use external deps lile angular material, but as you include the dependecies of angular material in the libs ngmodule (or with standalone components directly) they will be included in the generated app. no matter if the app is using those 3rd party lib in particular